# Using sed to add a URL to the start of every line

Tags: bash, sed, wget

I have the URL (see below) of a certain web page that lists many different
versions of a software package.

```
URL=http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/
```

The following one-liner gets me the latest version tar ball and its signature
file out of the HTML.

```
wget -qO- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ | grep tar | cut -d\" -f6 | tail -n4 | grep gz
```

Probably not the shortest most efficient one liner, but hey, I'm learning and
I'm open for feedback. The result of the above is this:

```
wget-1.15.tar.gz
wget-1.15.tar.gz.sig
```

Now, the next logical step (to me at least), is to pipe the output above into
`sed` and append the `$URL` to the front of each line so that the output looks
like:

```
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.15.tar.gz.sig
```

And then I want to pipe that right back into `wget` to download the files.

The question is this: How do I append the value of the bash variable `$URL` to
the front of each line of output using `sed`? I tried the following:

```
sed "s/^/$URL/"
```

But that only gives me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

I also know that the basic concept is good, because when I use the following, I
get good results...

```
VAR="Gorauskas, "
echo "Jonas" | sed "s/^/$VAR/"
```

So, my guess is that I need to somehow escape all of the `/` character in the
`$URL` variable... Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a different separator that doesn't contain any of the characters in the variable.

For example,

```
sed "s|^|$URL|"
```

(If you use `/` as the separator and the pattern or replacement also contain `/`, then you'd need to escape those.)

Comment: It works! So easy, and yet so hard... :)

Comment: Another character to watch in URLs (in the general case, not here) is `&` as it's special to `sed` on the right hand side of a substitution.

Answer (score 8):

What you do until now can be replaced by one `awk` call:

```
wget ... | awk -F\" '$6 ~ "gz$" { lastline=thisline; thisline=$6;}; '\
  'END {print lastline; print thisline;}'
```

And, of course, awk can add the URL, too:

```
awk -F\" -v baseurl="http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/" \
  '$6 ~ "gz" { lastline=thisline; thisline=$6;}; '\
  'END {print baseurl lastline; print baseurl thisline;}'
```

Comment: Very, very cool indeed!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `wget`'s `--base` option here:

```
wget -qO- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ |
  cut -d\" -sf6 |
  grep '\.tar\.gz' |
  tail -n2 |
  wget -i - --base=http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do the whole thing directly like so:

```
wget -qO- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ | grep tar.gz | cut -d\" -f6 | 
 tail -n2 | xargs -I{} wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/{}
```

This passes the output of the 1st `wget` to [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) which replaces the string `{}` with each of the results of the piped command.

And you can skip some parsing steps with some trickery:

```
wget -qO- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ | tac | grep -Pom 2 'href="\K(.+?.tar.gz)' | 
xargs -I{} wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/{}
```

Here, we are using [PCREs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (`-P`) with `grep` and `-o` so it only prints the matched portion of the line and `-m 2` to only print the 2 first matches. The `tac` call reverses the input so that the first 2 matches are actually the last (`tac` reverses its input, prints the last line as first, penultimate as second etc.).

The `\K` in the regular expression tells `grep` to ignore whatever came before the `\K` so that it is not printed when using `-o`.

---

Another approach, closer to what you had in  mind, would be to read the target files in a loop:

```
wget -qO- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ |tac | 
 grep -Pom 2 'href="\K(.+?.tar.gz)' | 
    while read target; do 
        wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/"$target"; 
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | sort -n  | sed "s|^|https://url.com/dl/p/|" > dl.txt

----
https://url.com/dl/p/28959-1080.mp4
https://url.com/dl/p/29482-1080.mp4
https://url.com/dl/p/29934-1080.mp4
https://url.com/dl/p/30654-1080.mp4
https://url.com/dl/p/30710-1080.mp4
----
```

Comment: Thank your for confirming that [devnull’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116658/86440) works. But please don’t add a new answer to do so; once you have sufficient
[reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation),
you will be able to [vote up questions and
answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that
you found helpful.